# using entity framework/nhibernate with sql2008 geography datatype

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, geography

I am using sql express 2008 and vs2008, writing in c#.

I have a db table with a Geography column in it, into which I need to put gps data I collected. When I tried creating an Entity-Framework mapping for this table, it just ignored the column with some warning about not being able to map such column types.
I then looked at nHibernate.Spatial project, but it seems like it only translates the Geometry types, not the Geography. No luck there.
I've been told I can use a view with casting the Geography to VarBinary, and then in the created entity class add another Property that deserializes the binary back into Geography. I guess that will work for reading the data from the db, but I also need to insert those rows into my db, and I can't add rows to the view.
Is there some other trick I can use in order to easily read and write Geography data from my db, in my c# code?

Comment: With NHibernate you ca use [NHibernate.Spatial](http://nhforge.org/wikis/spatial/introduction.aspx) for your better mapping.

Comment: as far as i can see NHiberate.Spatial only supports the geometry type yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know much about EF, but NHibernate allows you to extend it's type framework using `IUserType`. There's a bit about it on [Ray Houston's Blog](http://www.lostechies.com/blogs/rhouston/archive/2008/03/23/mapping-strings-to-booleans-using-nhibernate-s-iusertype.aspx).

I've successfully used this to create a type for that uses XmlSerialization to an Xml field, based on [Ayende's example](http://ayende.com/78/section.aspx/download/98)

Answer (score 0):

At this time Entity Framework v1 does not support SQL UDT - 2008 Spacial type is UDT.

You can store your long/lat data using WKB (byte[]/varbinary).

As a side note i did not notice any support for UDT during the Microsoft MIX09 for the next version (1.5 CTP). Perhaps i missed something.